# What is wrong when azure.datalake.store commands gives LISTERROR response?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-data-lake

Hi I am trying to access my Data Lake Store from a python program locally from my desktop. I get this strange error while executing the line

```
adl.ls('/')
```

The output is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\StefanFrost\adltest.py", line 31, in 
>       adl.ls('/')   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\azure\datalake\store\core.py", line
>   124, in ls
>       files = self._ls(path)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\azure\datalake\store\core.py", line
>   115, in _ls
>       out = self.azure.call('LISTSTATUS', key)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\azure\datalake\store\lib.py", line 362,
>   in call
>       self.log_response_and_raise(r, err)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\azure\datalake\store\lib.py", line 290,
>   in log_response_and_raise
>       raise exception azure.datalake.store.exceptions.DatalakeRESTException: Data-lake REST
>   exception: LISTSTATUS, .

I know that the firewall is open because the service is responding and I know that the supplied correct credentials, because I get unauthorized output when using the incorrect credentials. Below is the complete code.

```
from azure.datalake.store import core, lib, multithread
import logging, getpass, pprint, uuid, time

tenant_id = '<My Tenant Id>'
client_id = '<My Azure User Id>'
app_pwd = '<My Azure Password>'
datalake_nm = '<My Data Lake Store Name>'

token = lib.auth(tenant_id, client_id, app_pwd)

adl = core.AzureDLFileSystem(token, store_name=datalake_nm)

adl.ls('/')
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, Did you try to turn off the firewall and try?

Comment: Yes and if the limitation was actually the firewall then I wouldn't be able to connect either so it must be something.

Comment: Cold you add these lines to the beginning and run again? It should provide some more information.

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same error trying to connect an Azure Notebook to my data lake with a token.

Comment: @AmitKulkarni I ran the logging commands like you mentioned and it shows that this error: `{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Failed to validate the access token in the \'Authorization\' header` which is weird because I authenticated with lib.auth()` which gives you a link to sign on so I'm unsure why this is failing authentication.